# How to convert an input 'three four + five six =' to '34+56'?

Tags: c++, c, clion

I want to add two numbers together while each of them was described in its places.

For example, three four = 34, zero seven = 07, etc.

The largest addend needed to be processed is 99(nine nine)

How can I let the computer knows that 'three four equals to 34' and recognize each addends by the plus sign?

Comment: You will have to write an entire C++ program to do this. There is nothing in the C++ library that will do this for you, at a simple push of a button. You will have to do all the work yourself.

Comment: You could use a std::map. `std::map<std::string, int> digit; digit["one"] = 1;`. You get each number with `number = digit[firstDigit] * 10 + digit[secondDigit];`

Comment: Yeah, thanks for you all! I learned map method by myself and finally used it into my code. I use str.find and str.substr to separate each addends. All I want to know is a method which can provide the function I want, but not all the code :) @Sam Varshavchik

Answer (score 0):

generally, you have to define your input better in order to get an answer of how to parse it, but here is some pseudo code to get you started

`number_sentence` is a string like `"three four one eight"`

```
hashmap = {
    'one' : 1,
    'two' : 2,
    ...
}

def get_num(number_sentence):
    result = 0
    for digit_word in number_sentence:
        result = result * 10 + hashmap[digit_word]
    return result
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for you all! I learned map method by myself and finally used it into my code. I use str.find and str.substr to separate each addends. All I want to know is a method which can provide the function I want, but not all the code :) @Sam Varshavchik